# Assign Value To Dropdown Attribute

Tags: magento2

I am creating product programmatically its working fine now I have some attributes which are dropdown Like Brands now I want to assign brand with product when i am creating it programmatically how I can achieve this.

Comment: could you post your code here ?

Comment: How you importing products data? With the use of CSV?